# Style underline on a date with superscript

Tags: html, css

I have a line of html with inline css like this

```
<h2 style="text-decoration: underline;font-weight: bold;" >22<sup>nd</sup> of May 2017</h2>
```

There may be comments about this text format but this is not really the question (this is the way the requirement is written and although I'm sure I can get it changed if needs be I'm trying to do the initial page to the spec).

The above (in Chrome at any rate) moves breaks the underline and moves a mini underline section up to the superscript, which looks a bit silly to me.  I would rather just have one solid underline underneath the whole date ?  Ideally using inline script for now but if it requires a more sophisticated answer then so be it!

Thanks in advance if anyone can answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a text decoration use a bottom border:

```
<h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;font-weight: bold;" >22<sup>nd</sup> of May 2017</h2>
```

Comment: Also it might be worth while making the h2 element inline, floated, or a specific width, so that the border doesn't continue to 100% width of the page. I can update answer if you need help